# Consuming Api from OneOf

Tags: c#, rest

Consuming Api from OneOf
RestApi linked to returns an object that contains different types.

MessageTypeA:

```
{
  "sentDocumentStatusChangedMessage": {
    "documentId": "afa2e9e8-7f85-40d8-9954-ee33a93a3a9d",
    "messageId": "7b7a5409-cc99-4ac7-a387-dcd7a2103d73",
    "status": "SENT"
  }
}
```

or

MessageTypeB:

```
    {
      "documentReceivedMessage": {
        "documentId": "e21b220c-c16e-4c34-bd50-abbefd1fed96",
        "documentType": "INVOICE",
        "businessValidationReport": {
          "reportDate": "2021-10-18T10: 26: 27.000Z",
          "warnings": []
        },
        "messageId": "9409bfdc-0b05-403b-abf2-9a81aa4f59a6"
      }
    }
```

and a few more.

Since I have to deserialize them with json I have to give the type of object I expect.

```
response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<BrokerMessage>();
```

He could do it rigidly anyway

```
  public class BrokerMessage
    {
        public SentDocumentStatusChangedMessage SentDocumentStatusChangedMessage {get; set; }
        public DocumentReceivedMessage documentReceivedMessage {get; set; }
...
/// more classes
...
    }
```

But this code is poorly extensible.
Depending on the type I received, I have to do some different things.

What pattern to adopt to make the solution scalable, to add more supported messages / classes in the future?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.